# Conway's Game of Life Index Error

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

So I have to do the Conway's Game of Life with 5 rules:

1. A cell that has fewer than two live neighbors dies
2. A cell that has more than 3 live neighbors dies
3. A cell that is dead and has exactly 3 live neighbors comes to life
4. All edge cells stay 0
5. All other cells maintain their state

Example:

```
>>> A = [ [0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]

>>> printBoard(A)
00000
00100
00100
00100
00000

>>> A2 = next_life_generation( A )
>>> printBoard(A2)
00000
00000
01110
00000
00000

>>> A3 = next_life_generation( A2 )
>>> printBoard(A3)
00000
00100
00100
00100
00000
and so on... .
```

Notice, that next_life_generation( A ) returns a new board, so I can keep re-binding A to each successive generation
This is my code so far:

```
def countNeighbors(row, col, A):
count = 0
for row in range(len(A) - 1, len(A) + 2):
    for col in range(len(A) - 1, len(A) + 2):
        if A[row][col] == 1:
            count += 1
return count

def next_life_generation(A):
    for row in range(1, len(A) - 1):
        for col in range(1, len(A[0]) - 1):
            if A[row][col] == 0 and countNeighbors(row, col, A) == 3:
                A[row][col] = 1
            if countNeighbors(row, col, A) < 2:
                A[row][col] = 0
            elif countNeighbors(row, col, A) > 3:
                A[row][col] = 0
    return A
```

My problem is im getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    A = next_life_generation(A)
  line 88, in next_life_generation
    if countNeighbors(row, col, A) < 2:
  line 79, in countNeighbors
    if A[row][col] == 1:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `range(len(A) - 1, len(A) + 2)`  obviously contains indexes outside of the range of `A` (zero to `len(A)-1` are valid)   (Also array passing / return in Python probably doesn't work like you think it does re: "re-binding")

Comment: Could you please explain why range(len(A) - 1, len(A) + 2) is not valid?

Comment: You can try: http://pythontutor.com

Comment: @VinceCarter if `A=[3,2,5]` then `len(A) = 3`, and `A[2] = 5` if you index it, so `A[len(A) + 2]` would try to index the 5th element of `A`, and that does not exist.